# Just installed react-native-fullscreen-video and get this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Orientation.lockToPortrait')

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Just installed and linked react-native-fullscreen-video library and got this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Orientation.lockToPortrait')

Then I installed react-native-orientation library and get another error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 
>   '_reactNative.NativeModules.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants')

Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you have haven't linked the dependencies properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library requires **react-native-video** to be installed. Ensure that you have that dependency successfully installed and linked.